# How to copy elements of one array to another from different functions in Golang

Tags: arrays, function, go, copy, return

I want to know how to copy elements of one array returned by a function into another array in a different function.

Eg:

```golang
 func PossibleMoves()[8] int{
 /* calculations*/
 return Posmoves[]
}

func traversal(){

 var currentarray [8] int

copy(Posmoves,currentarray)
}
```

This shows an error saying undefined Posmoves, How should I correct it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) are *descriptors* (headers pointing to a backing array), not like [arrays](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) which are *values*. An array value means all its elements.

So in order to copy all the elements from one array into another, you don't need any "special" copy function, you just need to [assign](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) the array value.

Seriously, this is all what you need:

```
var currentarray [8]int = PossibleMoves()
```

Or you can use [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) and then it's just

```
currentarray := PossibleMoves()
```

See this simple example:

```
var a [8]int
var b = [8]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

fmt.Println(a, b)
a = b
fmt.Println(a, b)

a[0] = 9
fmt.Println(a, b)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZKDPrs1oQ2)):

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8] [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

As you can see, after the assignment (`a = b`), the `a` array contains the same elements as the `b` array.

And the 2 arrays are distinct / independent: modifying an element of `a` does not modify the array `b`. We modified `a[0] = 9`, `b[0]` still remains `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`Copy` function is used with two slices as arguments `(1 -> dst, 2 -> src)`, then, you must use two slices or convert your `[8]int` arrays to slices, you could do it using `[:]` operator. This operator will return a slice that will have a reference to `[8]int` array.

`Posmoves` is undefined because you didn't define in any place. Then, you could create a global variable:

```
var Posmoves [8]int

func main() {
    PossibleMoves()
    traversal()

    fmt.Println(Posmoves)
}


func PossibleMoves() [8]int {
    /* calculations*/
    return Posmoves
}

func traversal() {

    var currentarray [8]int

    copy(Posmoves[:], currentarray[:])
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9AHwF_bNMg)

It returns `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` because both arrays are initialized to zero value (default value).

You could execute `trasversal()` too and this will get `Posmoval array` from `PossibleMoves()`. So:

```
func main() {
    traversal()
}

func PossibleMoves() [8]int {
    /* calculations*/

    var Posmoves [8]int

    return Posmoves
}

func traversal() {

    var currentarray [8]int

    Posmoves := PossibleMoves()

    copy(Posmoves[:], currentarray[:])

    fmt.Println(currentarray)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BwUSpcK_OM)

The output will be again: `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

I hope it helps you! :-)

Comment: It gives a error saying panic:index of out range @ToniVillena

Comment: Could you give me a playgolang with your code, please? It would be easier

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/fo5AkWNbEo here is the code, also if your good at traversals(dfs)and you think my code is not right at some point, please let me know I am happy to change it. @ToniVillena

Comment: @Riya , your code has that fail because you try to do `strs[0] = currentSource`. And `currentSource` is initialized to zero (""). When you execute `IsValid(currentSource)`, you try to access to `0` and `1` position of string `b` (currentSource) (`b[0]` and `b[1]`), but length of `currentSource` or `b` is 0. Try this https://play.golang.org/p/XMbXWDLY9m

Comment: Just to Clarify..My input is two positions on the chessboard, and im trying to find the shortest path between the two using dfs, so I will have text file that has input like :A3,B2 D3,C4 etc. Coming to the error part I'm still getting the same error index out of range  @ToniVillena

Comment: @Riya , I'm viewing your playgolang. You have some fails so basic... If you wait, I will give you a playgolang. But, there are any things I don't understand too well

Comment: you can ask any questions related to that, i can explain and yes i will wait no problem @Toni Villena

Comment: @Riya, what kind of chess piece is? If your chess piece has "A1" position, it will have "C2" and "B3" how possible moves. Or, how does it works the movements? Has it a range? Is this behavior correct? https://play.golang.org/p/XdLlyFczX_

Comment: the chess piece is a knight, the function possible moves calculates moves for a given in the pattern of a knight, and the sort function below avoids the moves out of the board, the code you have written is correct instead the input should be from a text file. @Toni Villena